# Python scraping websites got Apache Tomcat/6.0.36 - Error report

Tags: javascript, apache, python-2.7, tomcat, web-scraping

I want to scrape a website using `requests` and `beautifulsoup`.

But it doesn't seem to work on [this website](http://mis.twse.com.tw/stock/fibest.jsp?stock=2412).

My Code:

```
site= "http://mis.twse.com.tw/stock/fibest.jsp?stock=2412"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

req = requests.get(site, headers = hdr, verify = False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text)
print soup
```

The error information below:

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.36 - Error report</title>
...
<pre>org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /view/headerView.jsp at line 35

32:     if(session.getAttribute(&quot;lang&quot;)==null)
33:     {
34:         String tempLang=request.getHeader(&quot;Accept-Language&quot;);
35:         tempLang=tempLang.replace(&quot;-&quot;,&quot;_&quot;);
36:         if(tempLang.indexOf(&quot;zh&quot;)&gt;=0)
37:         {
38:             lang=&quot;zh_tw&quot;;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String tempLang=request.getHeader(&quot;Accept-Language&quot;);
```

You need to pass in a header called `Accept-Language`.